# Does the work I do with a Live USB Drive or Live DVD leave any trail (eg: tmp files) on my machine?

Tags: security, livecd, liveusb

I want to know how Live DVD and USB drive work.

- Do they use the disk of my PC at all?
- If so, do they delete everything after I shut down the PC?
- If so, are the tmp files deleted securely? Or they can be recovered?

I'm thinking of a Live DVD like BackTrack, which is used for security tests, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They usually mount tmpfs to `/tmp`, which is an in-memory filesystem (like a ramdisk on steroids). So, it is as secure as your memory is.

Comment: Might want to check that your live CD isn't automatically mounting any Swap partitions or a persistence files (called "casper-rw" on Ubuntu) though.